# Using multiple instances of my custom Angular JS Directive on the same form

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I tried hard to solve this but couldn't get a possible solution.

I am using 2 instances of a directive on the same page to set value of 2 text fields with different values. but when i select one the other also changes to the same value.

Any insights into this will be appreciated as I am stuck from a long time on this issue.

I tried ngModel Isolate scope and all...

whenever I change one value the other also gets affected.

I cut few of my code and created a [plunker] http://plnkr.co/edit/xwsrThvbVsIXPotRHc7o. But cant happen to make that work as well.

My Template

```
      <input class="form-control" id="lovdat" name="lov" ng-             dblclick="dblClick()" ng-keyup="keyUp($event)" ng-model="lovval.displayval"
       type="text">
```

My Directive

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['LOVDirective']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.officeMaster = {

officeId: "",
officeName: "",
company: "",
companyId: "",
officeManager: "",
officeManagerId: "",
officeLocation: "",
isactive: ""

};
 $scope.lovvalemp = {
  displayval: "",
  dataval: ""
    }
  $scope.lovvalcomp = {
    displayval: "",
    dataval: ""
  }
});

angular.module('LOVDirective', [])
  .directive('Lov', [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        label: '@', // optional
        changeCallback: '&',
        lovval: '=info'

      },
      restrict: 'EA',

      replace: true, // optional 
      templateUrl: 'template.html',


      link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
        scope.param = {
          "LOVType": attr.gacLovType,
          "LOVSearchString": "",
          "LOVSearchCriteria": ""
        };

        scope.alertModalPopup = {};
        scope.alertModalPopup.selectedItem = "";



        scope.dblClick = function() {
          selectdata();
        };



        scope.selectdata = function() {
          //  var entityGrid = $("#lovGrid").data("kendoGrid");

          scope.lovval.displayval = attr.gacLovType + "Sherry";
          scope.lovval.dataval = attr.gacLovType + "1";
          lovval = scope.lovval;
          // lovval.ngModel = scope.lovval.dataval;
          //ngModel.$setViewValue(scope.lovval);
          //  $("#lovdat").val = scope.lovval.displayval;
          //  $('#lovPopup').modal('hide');
        };





      }

    };
  }]);
```

My Index.html

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label required" for="txthead">Manager</label>
      <lov ng-model="officeMaster.officeManager" data-gac-lov-type="EMPLOV" info="lovvalemp"></lov>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label required" for="txtoffice">Company</label>
      <lov ng-model="officeMaster.company" data-gac-lov-type="CMPLOV" info="lovvalcomp"></lov>

    </div>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what's supposed to happen when you double click a field? For me after fixing some syntax errors "EMPLOVSherry" appears when double clicking in the manager field, and "CMPLOVSherry" appears when double clicking the company field. That is to say, I can't seem to reproduce your problem here. http://plnkr.co/edit/lYkv2sK2pYNTPvQPPeNZ?p=preview

Comment: Thanks Fissio. Appreciate the quick response. I'm afraid i'm not able to see the updated Plunker. What I intend to do is both the inputs should have different value and should update the model as well with different value... double clickeing one should make that CMPLOVSherry and the other should make the second one  EMPLOVSherry

Comment: That's pretty much what's happening in the plunker I linked. Can you or someone else try and open it again to see if it's what you needed? Working fine for me, dunno what the issue there is :/

Comment: This is working fine... Let me try to replicate the issue by adding some more code that i require. I basically need to open a popup and select from a list.

Comment: Fissio, I added more functionality to the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/H02qy92KM48lQjgUave4?p=preview Please check it to see whats wrong. Basically the popuo shows a grid of 2 values and when one is selected the corresponding field needs to be updated. but both gets updated.

Comment: Your plunker seems to be broken (giving errors about missing functions / modules), can you fix it so I can take a look at the actual problem

Comment: Sorry made couple of changes to selection of data as well. http://plnkr.co/edit/H02qy92KM48lQjgUave4?p=preview

Comment: Uhh, okay. I'd advise against using jQuery in an angular project, or that's what I've heard - there's usually a better, more angular way of doing things you'd want to do with jQuery. That being said, I have no personal experience of jQuery, but as a guess I'd say you probably have an issue with your jQuery selector where it's selecting the *first* element with the specified ID instead of the one you'd want. See how jQuery and angular just don't go together very well here? EDIT: Checked https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/, and yes, the id selector only gets the first such element from DOM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not going to provide a straight up code solution - I'll point you in the right direction, though.

Continuing from the comments, I'm guessing your problem comes from the jQuery selectors - `$('#lovPopup')` and `$("#lovGrid")` which are selecting the first ones in DOM. Notice how the popup that shows up is the one beneath the first input? Upon inspecting the HTML, you can see that the second form is always hidden, no matter which input field you've doubleclicked, which is a result of invalid jQuery selectors.

I updated your plunker to get rid of basically all jQuery and to use `ng-show` to show and hide the modal. I'll leave correctly handling the kendo-grid to you. Here's an [example on how to use kendo-ui in angular.](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular)

Updated plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/3FhBL2ZtkxHOO6EJ3gKF?p=preview

Comment: Thanks a lot Fissio. Saved my life... better to do entire javascript the angular way. Solved it. :)